# warning C4273 -- inconsistent dll linkage for C code

Tags: c, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

A warning about inconsistent dll linkage is gained.

An [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273?view=msvc-170) was seen but I don't see the point for my case.

That stuff must be provided for 64 bit. I am aware that compiling is done with x64.

In shell.c, those lines are listed:

`#include <stdio.h>` is applied before following code:

```
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(WIN32)
# include <io.h>
#define isatty(h) _isatty(h)
#define access(f,m) _access((f),(m))
#undef popen
#define popen _popen
#undef pclose
#define pclose _pclose
#else
/* Make sure isatty() has a prototype.
*/
extern int isatty(int);
#endif
```

Line 78 is `FILE *popen(const char*,const char*);`

```
 /* popen and pclose are not C89 functions and so are sometimes omitted from
** the <stdio.h> header */ 
FILE *popen(const char*,const char*); 
int pclose(FILE*);
```

This is the warning:

```
c:\builds\pathShortened\3rdparty\ProjectA\shell\src\shell.c(78): warning C4273: "_popen": Inkonsistente DLL-Bindung.
```

This was the call in the build pipeline:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe /c /I..\StaticLib\src /I..\StaticLib\inc /I..\StaticLib\inc_priv /I"C:\builds\pathShortened\3rdparty\ProjectA\PathPartBuild\packages\openssl.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.x64.1.0.2.1\build\native\include" /I"C:\builds\pathShortened\3rdparty\ProjectA\PathPartBuild\packages\zlib.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.1.2.8.8\build\native\include" /Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /O2 /Oi /GL /D NDEBUG /D WIN32 /D _CONSOLE /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D _MBCS /Gm- /EHa /MD /Zp8 /GS- /Gy /Qpar /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"Bin\Release\x64\.tmp\\" /Fd"Bin\Release\x64\.tmp\vc141.pdb" /Gd /TC /FC /errorReport:queue /wd4005 /wd4505 /wd4514 /wd4131 Src\shell.c
```

EDIT: added line 78 + `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Usually this mean that you declare function with __declspec(dllimport) from one side, and implement it in code from another side

Comment: Hard to guess what line 78 contains.  Older CRT versions still had a declaration for popen(), optionally generating a warning that the posix subsystem names were deprecated.  The macro renames it, now there are two declarations of _popen.  You'd have to #include stdio.h *before* the macro definition to prevent that from happening.